# Using output of a pipe in sed for replacing in file

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I'm trying to use an output of a pipe as a variable that I'll pass to `sed`  to search and replace in file.

The contents of my `.env` file is

```
TEST=bla
TEST_2=blabla
```

and I want to replace `%TEST%` in my config.txt file

```
This is some fake config file. The value of test variable is %TEST%.
```

After replacement, this statement should be

```
This is some fake config file. The value of test variable is bla.
```

I've tried

```sh
grep 'TEST=' .env | sed 's/^.*=//' |  sed -i '' 's|%TEST%|$1|g' config.txt
```

But the result is

```
This is some fake config file. The value of test variable is $1.
```

How do I capture and use the output of a previous pipe in sed?

Comment: Variable are not expanded inside single `'` quotes. You want to make it work for any number of `env` variable? For `%TEST_2%` also?

Comment: You should do it like `repl="$(sed -n 's/^TEST=\(.*\)/\1/p'  .env)"` and then ``sed -i '' "s|%TEST%|$repl|g" config.txt``. Or even `sed -i '' "s|%TEST%|$(sed -n 's/^TEST=\(.*\)/\1/p' .env)|g" config.txt`

Comment: @KamilCuk for now, one is enough. I'll try with the suggestion Wiktor, thanks!

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that did the trick! Can you paste it as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest first extracting the text you need to replace with into a variable and then replace with it:

```
repl="$(sed -n 's/^TEST=\(.*\)/\1/p' .env)"
sed -i '' "s|%TEST%|$repl|g" config.txt
```

Or as an one-liner

```
sed -i '' "s|%TEST%|$(sed -n 's/^TEST=\(.*\)/\1/p' .env)|g" config.txt
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/RyZFtN)

Here, `sed -n 's/^TEST=\(.*\)/\1/p' .env` is extracting the text found on a line that starts with `TEST=` and is right after `TEST=` into `repl`.

Note that `"s|%TEST%|$repl|g"` is within double quotation marks, that allows variable expansion.

Also, if the string you want to replace with contains various "special chars" you may need to escape it, see [Is it possible to escape regex metacharacters reliably with sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29613304).